# Always need to rebuild project for generating Databinding class file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I need to rebuild the project everytime I code a new activity or Fragment using Databinding to generate it's corresponding DataBinding class. Can anyone throw some light on it?

Comment: I am facing this same issue. but  I think it's of android studio 3.1.

Comment: Moreover Android Studio 3.1 have become more laggy. I am facing too much of lag inspite of Good Hardware Configurations and well managed Custom VM Options.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: The latest canary of 3.2 includes databinding v2 as standard. It apparently makes it more responsive. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-32-canary-9-now-available.html